# Importing ArcGIS Vector Layer "drawingInfo" to apply to QGIS layer style?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server

It is possible to import vector layers in GeoJSON format either directly from an ArcGIS MapServer URI, or from a local JSON file sourced from such. ArcGIS JSON has a "drawingInfo" key (example below). My question is whether QGIS can interpret this data (colours, transparency etc.) and apply it to layer style properties? Currently, if I import JSON from an ArcGIS MapServer source this data seems to be ignored and style is set automatically.

```
"drawingInfo": {
    "renderer": {
      "type": "simple",
      "symbol": {
        "type": "esriSFS",
        "style": "esriSFSSolid",
        "color": [
          198,
          232,
          201,
          255
        ],
        "outline": {
          "type": "esriSLS",
          "style": "esriSLSNull",
          "color": [
            130,
            130,
            130,
            255
          ],
          "width": 0
        }
      },
      "label": "",
      "description": ""
    },
    "transparency": 0,
    "labelingInfo": null
  }
```